# NSToolbarItem and Auto Layout

Tags: cocoa, autolayout, nstoolbar

I have a window with a programmatically created toolbar, which is populated with an NSToolbarItem that has a custom view defined in a xib file. If I check "Translate Masks into Contraints" for the view, then it doesn't resize itself correctly, so its content gets squashed even though I set its compression resistance priority to 750. If I uncheck that on the other hand, then I get a "Detected missing constraints" error at runtime. Also, the content of my view then resizes itself correctly, but it ends up clipped like so:

[image: Example of clipped content]

So it looks like the toolbar sticks my view into a container view and, in order to get the correct behaviour, I should set up layout constraints that allow my view to position itself correctly. However, I don't see how to access that container view... Any idea what I am doing wrong?

I am probably missing something obvious since one would think that this is a very standard setup, but Google didn't come up with anything.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, I opened a support request with Apple, the outcome of which is that this is now being treated as a bug by Apple.

In case anyone else runs into this, a good workaround is to create an intermediate view which contains the toolbar view as a subview with constraints `@"H:|[toolbarView]"` and `@"V:|[toolbarView]"`, has `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=YES` and to use this view as the toolbar item. It then suffices to listen for size change notifications of `toolbarView` and to adjust the size of its superview accordingly.